# am trying to clone my git repository using git bash but am getting an invalid argument error

Tags: git, git-bash

cannot mkdir https://github.com/muliann/iris_Dataset-Classification.git: Invalid argument

Answer (score 2):

You clone *to* a folder. 
Here is what I would do:

```
git clone https://github.com/muliann/iris_Dataset-Classification.git
```

This will automatically create a folder called iris_Dataset-Classification which will then act as your local copy of the repo.